# Can I use Spock test in Koltin Multiplatform project? If so how to set in gradle.build.kts?

Tags: kotlin, spock, kotlin-multiplatform

I try to use Spock test framework in my Kotlin multiplatform project, but with fail, the gradle script:

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.4.30"
    kotlin("multiplatform") version kotlinVersion
    application
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version kotlinVersion
    groovy // for spock
}
repositories {
    // ...
    maven("https://jitpack.io") // for spock
}
kotlin {
    jvm {withJava()}
    js {/*...*/}
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {/*...*/}
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {/*...*/}
        }
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                dependsOn(commonTest)
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                // implementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
                // for spock
                implementation("org.spockframework.spock:spock-core:spock-1.3")
                implementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.7")
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {/*...*/}
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the `spock-1.3` and `spock-2.0-M4` with `groovy-2.5` and `Junit5`, all failed with dependencies problems, even thought the test can run, it tells: **Test events were not received**, and more important:

I **cannot** create groovy source fold for test only.(The directory appreas like normal folder, not source or test folder)

How to configure the dependencies or `gradle.build.kts` file? Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I can now make **Spock** work with existed **Ktor** project with the code below added to my `gradle.build.kts` :

```
plugins {
    groovy
}

repositories {
    maven("https://jitpack.io")
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework.spock:spock-core:spock-1.3")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        withConvention(GroovySourceSet::class) {
            groovy {
                setSrcDirs(listOf("src"))
            }
        }
    }
    test {
        withConvention(GroovySourceSet::class) {
            groovy {
                setSrcDirs(listOf("test"))
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}
```

However, I cannot figure out the **Koltin Multiplatform** project with **Spock** test, I will post the script when I make it.